# Purging Recent to avoid confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution, visual-studio-project

Is there a way to remove certain projects/solutions from the Visual Studio menu `FILE` -> `Recent Projects and Solutions` besides deleting the solutions/folders?

I believe that it will prompt you if you delete it, but this seems like overkill.

Comment: Although apparently you could [do this more easily in 2010.](http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2010/02/ten-features-in-visual-studio-2010-you.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by modifying your registry. There is a registry entry like the following:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectMRUList
```

The `11.0` corresponds to Visual Studio 2012, but it is probably similar for other versions. Here you will see multiple entries that look something like the following:

[image]

From here you can delete any File that you don't want to appear in the recent solutions list.

I found this information as part of the community feedback for [How to: Remove Items from the Recent Projects List on the Start Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991991%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).